# Add New Sub Site from the WordPress back end then in sub site options table option_value must be with https

Tags: multisite, options, subdomains, ssl, https

I installed multi site setup for the domain https://uninfo.org but when i add new sub site from the back end it is creating but in sub site WP-options table it created with HTTP rather then https because i have setup https on all sub domain or main site even sub site also working with when i have manually updated site URL i need to auto functioning it on the time of 'add new sub site' & in sub site option table show sub site URL with https.
Kindly revert me appropriate answer anyone

Answer (score 0):

You Can try force SSL with any 3rd part plugin or hardcoded in wp-config 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/

Comment: Yeah, you can. But you should not. You should configure SSL once and not force it every time someone visits your site...